# What is § called and how do I type it?

Tags: meaning, american-english, symbols

I copy pasted this symbol from

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3

but I want to know what it is called and how to make it.

Comment: Just found this by putting the symbol in to wikipedia ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A7

Comment: I'm confused; how did you type the symbol in your question?

Comment: `I copy pasted this symbol from `

Comment: I understand that; I did read that earlier, but I felt it would be unfair to the person who answered correctly to change my answer after the fact.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The § is the **section sign** or **[section mark](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/section-mark)**.

You can type it in Windows by holding down Alt and pressing 2 then 1 on the numeric keypad.

In Linux you can hold Ctrl-Shift-U and then, keeping Ctrl & Shift held, type A then 7 then Enter.

Comment: Be warned that not all Linux graphic desktops and applications support the (excellent) Ctrl+Shift+U shortcut for entering Unicode hexadecimal code points. For example, KDE generally does not support it, and offers an (inferior, IMHO) alternative in the form of the [compose key](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=39343).

Answer (score 1):

It's a section sign. It indicates a section in a body of writing. It's commonnly found in US codified laws.

Instead of saying Chapter 2, Section 9 of the US code, you would write 2 USC §9